# Imagemagick font_stretch or spacing between letters?

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, spaces

I am generating some buttons using ImageMagick. However, I am not able to set the spacing between the letters in generated image. Command which I use:

```
convert -gravity center button_subscribeme.png -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf  -fill white -draw "text 0,0 'CLICK ME'"  -font_stretch 10  render/mailbox-submit.png
```

throws:

```
convert: unrecognized option `-font_stretch' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1561.
```

So I guess font_strech is not proper option. How I can achieve it? Generated text is too narrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no ImageMagick parameter named `-font_stretch` that I know of. However, there is `-stretch`.

But I don't think that `-stretch` really works with fonts. In any case, to find out what sort of values are possible, just run:

```
convert -list stretch
```

and see the result:

```
Any
Condensed
Expanded
ExtraCondensed
ExtraExpanded
Normal
SemiCondensed
SemiExpanded
UltraCondensed
UltraExpanded
```

### Use `-kerning` !

Better use the `-kerning` commandline parameter. It takes positive as well as negative values:

```
convert \
  in.png \
 -gravity center \
 -font "/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf" \
 -kerning -0.5 \
 -fill white \
 -draw "text 0,0 'CLICK ME'" \
  out1.png
```

or

```
convert \
  in.png \
 -gravity center \
 -font "/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf" \
 -kerning 1.5 \
 -fill white \
 -draw "text 0,0 'CLICK ME'" \
  out2.png
```

Works for me on ImageMagick version 6.7.8-3 2012-07-19 on Mac:

[image: <code>-kerning -0.5</code>] [image: <code>-kerning 1.5</code>]

Comment: Och, I believe I was looking for this one! I will let you know after weekend when I will check!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `-stretch` and takes an enumerated parameter instead of number.

Check this link: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#stretch

Comment: Yes, seems like this one - but I just checked -stretch with different parameters and it does not change anything :(

Comment: @bluszcz Can you send me your full new command with `-stretch`?

Comment: convert -gravity center button_subscribeme.png -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf  -fill white -draw "text 0,0 'CLICK ME'"  -stretch UltraExpanded  render/mailbox-submit.png